# Counters for graphs in oral presentations?

Tags: counters, spoken-language

I have to make a Japanese presentation and I'd like to say "I'll explain japanese demographics using three graphs", but then realized I didn't know the counter for graphs.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 5):

Use 「3つのグラフ」 or 「3枚【まい】のグラフ」.　Whichever is OK, but maybe the latter will sound just a little bit more formal.

Answer (score -1):

If you use three graphs in one page, say 「３つのグラフ」.
If you use three graphs in each separate page,  say 「3まいのグラフ」